# Acceptable power bank for MSI gaming laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power-bank

My laptop is a GL62M 7RDX.  The AC adapter says:

- INPUT 100-240V ~1.8A 50-60Hz
- OUTPUT 19.5 V === 6.92 A a 135 W

I am considering using the following power bank: [MAXOAK 50000mAh 185wh 6 Port(5/12/20v) Portable Charger External Battery Power Bank for Laptop & Notebook-Most of Sony Dell Hp Toshiba Samsung Lenovo Acer IBM NEC Mobile,Tablet(not for Apple Laptop)](https://www.amazon.ca/MAXOAK-50000mAh-Portable-External-Notebook-Most/dp/B00YP823NA/)

Is it compatible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking if hardware is compatible are off topic. See [help/on-topic] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not... as you require 6.25 A and the supply can only give 5 A. However, I must admit that it looks interesting, if you had a laptop that required less than a 5 A supply.

You should look for something that can supply at least 150 W, or 8-9 A, to be safe and have a nice margin for current/power spikes, and not burn out the supply. You *could* get a 20 V 7 A 140 W supply but it is a bit close to the maximum requirements.

Even better still, buy the correct adapter, either from the manufacturer (which would probably be rather pricey) or an OEM supply (which would be not so pricey, but just as good).